# with declarative style, how to add new key/value pair in existing dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, declarative

need to add new key/value pair in existing dictionary.

I beleive there should be the way of doing it with declarative style
something like

```
     new_data = [x['new_key']=1 for x in simplejson.loads(data)]
```

(gives syntax error)

how to do something similar ?

EDIT:
I need not to merge, but edit existed dict or create or duplicate

Comment: `existing_dict['new_key'] = 'new_value'`? If you have a *list* of dictionaries, you can simply loop on them and add for each..

Comment: of course, but, maybe something more pythonic (laconic) and elegant way exists?

Comment: Why are you doing this in a list comprehension?!

Comment: Are you trying to add the same (key,value) pair to each dictionary in a *list* of dictionaries?

Comment: just for typing speed purpose

Comment: @Anonymous well that doesn't seem to have sped you up much, now does it?